# MVC3 - Controller returns view from the Root and not from Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to achieve a multi tenant MVC3 application. All the url requests including subdomain requests are directed to the main application. Solution is having the default main controllers and an area named "Clients". So there are 2 routes.

This on in the clientarea

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Client_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new {controller = new ClientAreaConstraint()},
            new[] { "MainApp.UI.Areas.Clients.Controllers" });
```

This in the global asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MainApp.UI.Controllers" }
        );
```

One for the area and one for the main one. In the route of the area, I have added a route constraint which checks whether the url has a subdomain to it, If yes it returns true.

```
public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
        var clientName = url.Split('.')[1];
        return clientName != "mainsite";
    }
```

This works and the area controller is getting the subdomain requests. But when i try to call return View(). It looks for the View in the main folder and not in the Area folder. 
My url looks like this 
http://www.client.mainsite.com/ and it doesn't have the area name. Is it because of that ?
What could be the problem ? Please help

Comment: Found the Problem, I had renamed the Area name during the development. I renamed the folder and class names. but failed to rename the "Areaname" in the Area Registration file which caused the fallback and view to be picked from the root. In the root i had a same controller and same view folder

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a virtual path is mapped as the area name. I set area address in visual studio just to debug and it asked me to create a virtual path. So AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath was always ~/ and routing wasn't able to determine the area. For IIS express delete the virtual path for your site:

C:\Users\username\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

I spent 4 days to discover it.